# Post slider loads vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, loading

All post sliders on [this site](http://www.bensoncompany.co.uk/coaching/) load vertically for a few seconds before it loads. All the styles load - it' s the javascript that's affecting it.

Can it simply be because it loads over 50 fairly sized images?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with load times. You could theoretically use your css to make them automatically render side-by-side with floats or inline-block and then in the javascript file disable that css by removing the class or simply removing the css. If it were me I wouldn't worry about it though. On my machine I could barely scroll down fast enough to see the vertical load. It could be an issue for users with slower internet I suppose.